# Selecting multiple DOM elements in React

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I made simple React component with some images that I want to animate as they are shown in viewport. To use  getboundingclientrect() method I have to pass an element so I used js querySelectorAll('img') in componentDidMount() where my scrollEventListener is. It doesn't feel like the right way to go (although works fine). Is there more 'Reactish' solve for that problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to use [Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

With React, usually you shouldn't have to use native dom selectors. By using refs it stays in the React scope and you'll have a more robust workflow.

Comment: Is there a way to quickly use refs for multiple elements like querySelectors or do I have to assign them 'manually'?

Comment: @Bruinen You can maintain multiple refs in an array or object and use them in your `render`.